# Null value stored in xml Column Table variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, rss

the below return a Null in @xmlT (table).
In one machine it works fine and in other machine returns Null also if i change URL then the same thing happens, i mean it returns Null.

```
declare  @xmlT TABLE ( yourXML XML )
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @QS varchar(50)

SELECT @URL = 'http://indianexpress.com/section/world/feed/'
```

**--SELECT @URL = 'http://www.greaterkashmir.com/feed.aspx?cat_id=2'**

```
                     or
```

**--SELECT @URL = 'http://www.spa.gov.sa/english/rss13.xml'**

```
DECLARE @Response varchar(max)
DECLARE @XML xml
DECLARE @Obj int 
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 

EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 

INSERT @xmlT ( yourXML )
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 


DECLARE  @tlb table(customerlist xml)
```

**//below statement returns Null on some URL's and on other Machines**

```
select * from @xmlT  


 SELECT   N.C.value('description[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') ItemId,   N.C.value('title[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') Value
FROM @tlb CROSS APPLY CustomerList.nodes('//channel/item') N(C)
```

Comment: is it possible that you have different access rights on different machines?

Comment: then what about diffrent URL's on same Machine ?

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but if the URL's and the process works fine on one machine then I would think that there is an access issue with the other machine. But that is only a guess.

Comment: thanks Dear @KamranFarzami

Comment: Can help me Converting link data into Standard XML in SQL-Server  http://www.arabnews.com/cat/50/rss.xml